# Does spring form taglib disabled attribute really have to resolve to a string?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I've been playing around with the spring form taglib lately and came across a fairly disturbing phenomenon.

```
<form:select path="whatever" disabled="${true}">
```

Will render a select element that is NOT disabled

```
<form:select path="whatever" disabled="${'true'}">
```

Will render a select element that IS disabled.

This indicates to me that the tag expects a string in that attribute and is refusing to coerce any boolean values (possibly checking the type first).

The impact is that I'm unable to do something like `<form:select path="whatever" disabled="${someOtherfield.selectedId != -1}" />` which is something that happens fairly often in our system.

Am I simply missing some part of the form taglibs functionality?  Is this a legitimate design decision?  A defect?

Comment: I was going to suggest raising this on the Spring forum and/or JIRA, but I see you already have a whole thread to yourself and a JIRA issue :)

Comment: I have yet to have a response to any of my questions on the spring forum, I think that's out of about 10 or so threads over a couple of years.
So while I still keep on trying, I really only post there because I feel it's the right place.  Not because I feel it's likely to yield any answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I did some more digging around this one, because the work-arounds were looking too ugly.

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=84102

The problem was that the JSP was evaluating the el, and blindly comparing the result of that evaluation using "true".equals

Comparing a String to a Boolean using that method will always return false because the type's don't match so it's definitely a defect.

Fortunately the isDisabled method at fault is a protected one liner, so I have been able to work around it by extending the 8 input tag's effected and overriding that method to do a slightly more robust comparison.

So the answer is, yes, it is a defect, and from skaffman's comments it looks like it's a bit of a problem with an old library not being very well updated as JSP EL was implemented.

Thanks for your answers guys

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit odd, right enough. The Spring source code shows that the `disabled` property of `SelectTag` is `String`, not `boolean`. This is clearly not the right thing to do, but I suspect it's still that way for legacy reasons (spring-form.tld pre-dates JSP EL).

That leaves it up to the JSP runtime to coerce a `boolean` into a `String`, and apparently it won't do this. I'm less surprised about this, since JSP EL is notoriously limited.

So you're caught between two semi-broken implementations. You'll just need to make sure you pass String values to that attribute.

Comment: from what I can see the tld uses a spring eval mechanism that supports both JSP2 EL and JSP1 EL, so I think it's just a small bug in an implementation that tries to maintain backwards compatibility rather than an abhorrent design flaw

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this design is that they have a special fallback code to force EL expression evaluation when container doesn't evaluate it. For example, this code:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored = "true" %>
...
${'Simple text'} <spring:message text = "${'Message text'} />"
```

produces `${'Simple text'} Message text`

Probably, it's useful for some strange legacy container configurations.

That is, the following code wouldn't work if they make `disabled` attribute `boolean`:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored = "true" %>
...
<form:select ... disabled = "${true}" />
```