# EL inside form:input causes unclosed tag error

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

When I try to do things like `<c:if ...>...</c:if>` inside a `form:input` tag I get the error in my console that the `form:input` has not been closed.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens, and the cleanest solution? (maybe a `set var` and then `${result of c:if}`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSP tags, unlike HTML tags, have a special meaning in JSP syntax, therefore you can't use EL expressions in arbitrary places of JSP tags. EL expressions can only be used in their attributes, so you need something like this (note that `name` and `id` are not needed, they are inferred from `path`):

```
<form:input path="x" title="x(dd/MM/yyyy)" maxlength="10" size="10" 
    class = "${(empty eee) ? 'date' : ''}" 
    disabled = "${(not empty ccc) ? 'true' : 'false'}" />
```

Comment: something like <form:input type="text" ... <c:if test="${empty bla">disabled="disabled"</c:if>/>

Comment: <form:input path="x" id="x" name="x" title="x(dd/MM/yyyy)" maxlength="10" size="10" ${(empty eee) ? 'class="date"' : ''} ${(not empty ccc) ? 'disabled="disabled"' : ''} />  still results in a unterminated input tag error

Comment: @Ralph: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187851/does-spring-form-taglib-disabled-attribute-really-have-to-resolve-to-a-string

Comment: @axtvt: interesting - Bug is fixed in Spring 3.0.1 (https://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-6790)

Answer (score 4):

You can not use `<c:if>` this way:

```
<form:input type="text" ... <c:if test="${empty bla}">disabled="disabled"</c:if>/>
```

In your case you have to write:

```
<form:input type="text" ... disabled="${empty bla}" />
```

(Pay attention to a related bug fixed in Spring 3.0.1 https://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-6790)